# Read a File with a Header and Extract the Data

Tags: matlab, file-io

I am trying to pull data from a file. The file contains 37 columns, each with a heading. I cannot seem to pull out only the data. I am not sure what function to use. Eventually I will need to perform some calculations and then output some more data.

I have tried using dlmread, textscan, load and a few others. I do not really understand how these functions interact with different types. I have double checked that I am opening the correct file and that the file is filled with values.

```
% Prompt user to select the folder containing the data
testfolder = uigetdir();

datastore = zeros (0,37); 


for i= 1:2

   subfoldertxt = [testfolder, '\t.txt'];

   %datastore = dlmread(subfoldertxt,',');

    store = textscan(subfoldertxt,'%s','delimiter',',', 'HeaderLines', 37 
);
datastore = textscan(subfoldertxt,'%f', 'delimiter','\t');

 %There are 37 columns. 18 are used as pairs, one column (the 15th) is left 
over.  
for column = 1:18

   if column < 15
Error(:,column)=datastore(:,column) - datastore (:, column + 18);
   elseif column >15
Error(:,column)= datastore(:,column) -datastore(:, column + 19);
   end
end
```

I want data store to hold the values from the file so that Error can be calculated. Currently I am getting either a 1x1 cell array that is completely empty.

Comment: I don't know if it's a coincidence ... but `'HeaderLines'` is not meant to indicate the number of columns

Comment: Please show some example data (a *minimal* example would only have a few columns, the fact your data has 37 is irrelevant). It is important what data types you're dealing with.

Comment: Why not just use [readtable](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)?